# Print output to file on python

Tags: python, file, printing

I have two python files. My test.py import td.py file witch i found internet. Td.py file looking signals from TelldusCenter program.

Now if i run test.py file it shows me signals what i get from TelldusCenter app and output is something like: "Door - ON"
Now i like to print that "Door - ON" text to file but i dont know how.

Here is my test.py file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import td
import time


def myDeviceEvent(deviceId, method, data, callbackId):
    print '%s' %( td.getName(deviceId) )+' - %s' %(td.methodsReadable.get(method, 'Unknown' ))


td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent)



try:
    while(1):
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print 'KeyboardInterrupt received, exiting'
```

"td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent)" print output to terminal now. I try to print that to file but it just give me error.

```
 a = open("output.txt", "w") 
 a.write(td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "testi.py", line 11, in
>   
>       a.write(td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent))  TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Show us the code fo `td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent)`.

Comment: What's `td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent)` return value and type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
def myDeviceEvent(deviceId, method, data, callbackId):
    print '%s' %( td.getName(deviceId) )+' - %s' %(td.methodsReadable.get(method, 'Unknown' ))
```

to

```
def myDeviceEvent(deviceId, method, data, callbackId):
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as outputFile:
        outputFile.write('%s' %( td.getName(deviceId) )+' - %s' %(td.methodsReadable.get(method, 'Unknown' )))
```

You can use `with` statement to handle files and its scope. You dont have to worry about the closing the file properly, when you use `with`. That takes care of it.

**Edit:** You can use modern string formatting like this. Read more about it here http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting

```
def myDeviceEvent(deviceId, method, data, callbackId):
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as outputFile:
        outputFile.write('{} - {}'.format(td.getName(deviceId), td.methodsReadable.get(method, 'Unknown')))
```

Answer (score 1):

From my interpretation of the code, `td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent)` registers a callback. It does not produce a string itself. This is why you cannot output the 'result' of the registration.

Instead try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import td
import time

a = open("output.txt", "w") 

def myDeviceEvent(deviceId, method, data, callbackId):
    a.write('%s' %( td.getName(deviceId) ) + ' - %s' %(td.methodsReadable.get(method, 'Unknown')

td.registerDeviceEvent(myDeviceEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) with a basic configuration :

```
import logging
FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT, filename='Output.txt', level=logging.INFO)

logging.info('My message')
```

File `Output.txt` :

```
2013-10-17 09:26:08,496 - My message
```